# Login,register and verify OTP API project with Django rest framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to make an API project in which a person can Login, register with a phone number and OTP.

**What we need to do in this project**

1. Login and Register from the same page.
2. Verify OTP from verify image.
3. When user gets register for the first time mobile number, otp, a random username,a random picture from a folder,a random profile id, a name whic is the same as mobile number gets alloted in the database.

**Here's my code**

**modals.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to ='profile/')
    profile_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = User
           fields = ['mobile']
       def create(self, validated_data):
                
                    instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
                    global totp
                    secret = pyotp.random_base32()
                    totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret, interval=300)
                    otp = totp.now()
                    instance = self.Meta.model.objects.update_or_create(**validated_data, defaults=dict(otp=str(random.randint(1000 , 9999))))[0]            
                    instance.save()
                    return instance
    
    class VerifyOTPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['mobile','otp']
            
        def create(self,validated_data):
            
            instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
            mywords = "123456789"
            res = "expert@" + str(''.join(random.choices(mywords,k = 6)))
            path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
            dir_list = os.listdir(path)
            random_logo = random.choice(dir_list)
            instance = self.Meta.model.objects.update_or_create(**validated_data, defaults = dict(username = res,name = instance.mobile ,logo = random_logo, profile_id = res))[0]
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

**views.py**

```
def send_otp(mobile,otp):
    url = "https://www.fast2sms.com/dev/bulkV2"
    authkey = settings.AUTH_KEY
    querystring = {"authorization":authkey,"variables_values":otp,"route":"otp","numbers":mobile}
    headers = {
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(response.text)


class RegistrationAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        mobile = request.data['mobile']
        data = User.objects.filter(mobile = mobile).first()
        if data is not None:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            mobile = request.data['mobile']
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                instance = serializer.save()
                content = {'mobile': instance.mobile, 'otp': instance.otp}
                mobile = instance.mobile
                otp = instance.otp
                print("Success")
                send_otp(mobile,otp)
                return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response({"Error": "Login in Failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            mobile = request.data['mobile']
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
               
                instance = serializer.save()
                content = {'mobile': instance.mobile, 'otp': instance.otp}
                mobile = instance.mobile
                otp = instance.otp
                send_otp(mobile,otp)
                return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response({"Error": "Sign Up Failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class VerifyOTPView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = VerifyOTPSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = VerifyOTPSerializer(data=request.data)
        mobile = request.data['mobile']
        otp_sent = request.data['otp']

        if mobile and otp_sent:
            old = User.objects.filter(mobile=mobile)
            if old is not None:
                old = old.first()
                otp = old.otp
                if str(otp) == str(otp_sent):
                    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
                    mobile = request.data['mobile']
                    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                        instance = serializer.save()
                        content = {'mobile': instance.mobile, 'otp': instance.otp, 'name':instance.name, 'username':instance.username, 'logo':instance.logo, 'profile_id': instance.profile_id }
                        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                else:
                        return Response({
                            'status' : False, 
                            'detail' : 'OTP incorrect, please try again'
                        })
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**Application's urls.py**

```
path('register/', RegistrationAPIView.as_view()),
    path('verify', VerifyOTPView.as_view()),
```

Now, there are two problems.

1. The random image is not getting saved in database i get error of not found.
2. i am getting all the results i want when i register everything gets alloted fine except images but when i login with the same mobile number all the data gets updated again and i get everything new in the database. i don't want anything updated except otp.Otp should get updated everytime user login with the number but data should remain same as it was alloted at the time of registeration.